# R: Find files containing exact string match followed only by _ (ignore case)

Tags: r, stringr

I have files called

```
value<-c("ABC_Seed_1_0.csv", "ABC_Seed_1_1.csv", "ABC_Seed_10_0.csv", "ABC_Seed_10_1.csv")
```

I would like to only find and delete files that belong to file: seed_1.tar.xz (i.e. find all files called ACB_Seed_1_*.csv)

Problem I have is that if I search for seed_1 I will also get seed_10. Is there a trick?

I've tried adding the "_" using paste0

```
    #Available files
    value<-c("ABC_Seed_1_0.csv", "ABC_Seed_1_1.csv", "ABC_Seed_10_0.csv", "ABC_Seed_10_1.csv")

    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    #File to match against (minus extension)
    file<-c("seed_10.tar.xz")

    ListToDelete<- value %>% 
    as_tibble %>% 
    filter(value, 
    stringr::str_detect(string = value, pattern = paste0(fixed(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file, compression = TRUE),ignore_case = TRUE),"_"))
    
    #Returns an empty tibble


    file.remove(ListToDelete)
```

Comment: There is definitely a regex to do that but you can also use `stringr::word()`, i.e. `stringr::word(value, 3, sep = '_') == '1'`

Comment: Using Tim's regex you could also use `grep("ABC_Seed_1_\\d+.csv", value, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve the previous answer ... assuming that your file names are standard, first split the input using `strsplit` and extract the Seed number, then use `grepl` as suggested.

E.g.

```
value[grepl(paste("Seed_",as.numeric(strsplit(file, "[_|.]")[[1]][2]),"_",sep=""), value, fixed=TRUE)]
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns all my files though. I only want seed_1 or seed_10 not both.

Comment: That's odd, it works as intended here. The `grepl` on both preceding and following underscores should eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: Ahh I'm so sorry, I made a mistake. My tar csv files are ABC_Seed1_0.tar.xz

Comment: OK so if I take the first _ away it works

Comment: Great, so the confusion is solved :) It really pays to learn some regex basics for this kind of problems, the `grep` family is very useful.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've been trying to avoid grep for years and years....

Answer (score 2):

You might be making this more complicated than it needs to be.  In base R, I would just use `grepl` here:

```r
value[grepl("ABC_Seed_1_\\d+.csv", value)]
[1] "ABC_Seed_1_0.csv" "ABC_Seed_1_1.csv"
```

**Data:**

```
value <- c("ABC_Seed_1_0.csv",  "ABC_Seed_1_1.csv",
           "ABC_Seed_10_0.csv", "ABC_Seed_10_1.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're right I always make things more complicated. I'm looking for find seed_1 from the seed_1.tar.xz filename in the value vector so how would I put it into that grepl function? Here you've put in a specific string but first I need to split seed_1.tar.xz and then feed it in, no? I should clarify that all this is in a for loop so I will later need to extract all files belonging to seed_10, etc (sorry if this was not clear)